# Counting values between two files perl

Tags: perl

I have an issue to solve,

I have 2 files.

File A col1,col2, col3

File A

```
201843,12345,30
201844,33333,10
```

File B col1,col2,col3, col4, col5, col6

```
201843,12345,1,2,0,5
201843,12345,2,4,0,5
201843,12345,3,4,2,5
201843,12345,4,4,5,5
201844,33333,1,0,0,10
201844,33333,2,0,0,10
201844,33333,3,0,9,10
201844,33333,4,0,9,10
201844,33333,5,0,10,10
```

I need to count how many times the file B match with File base in two parameters:
Param 1: My keys will be matched with col1 and col2
Param 2: Col5 from File B need to be greater than zero.

So the result for each line in File B will be this way. Adding a new Col in the last position.

```
201843,12345,3,4,2,5,2
201843,12345,4,4,5,5,2
201844,33333,3,0,9,10,3
201844,33333,4,0,9,10,3
201844,33333,5,0,10,10,3
```

But I am getting this result and I do not want it:

```
201843,12345,3,4,2,5,5
201843,12345,4,4,5,5,5
201844,33333,3,0,9,10,5
201844,33333,4,0,9,10,5
201844,33333,5,0,10,10,5
```

I have used this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
$|=1;

my $FILEA = $ARGV[0];
my $FILEB = $ARGV[1];

open ( FA, '<', $FILEA ) || die ( "File $FILEA Could not be found!" );
open ( FB, '<', $FILEB ) || die ( "File $FILEB Could not be found!" );


my %hash;
while ( <FA> ){
        chomp;
        my($col1, $col2, $col3) = split ",";
        $hash{$col1,$col2}=$col3;

}

my $count=0;
while ( <FB> ){
        chomp;
        my($cl1, $cl2, $cl3, $cl4, $cl5, $cl6) = split ",";
        if(exists($hash{$cl1,$cl2}) and ($cl5 > 0)){
        $count++;
        }
        if ($cl5 > 0){
                print join(",",$$cl1, $cl2, $cl3, $cl4, $cl5, $cl6,$count);
        }
}
```

Comment: $hash{$week,$item}=$Ttl_Rmn; is an unusual hash. Second, how are you loading the hash, viz. $col1 =! $week (obviously).

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the script. Now is the original one.

Comment: What is this new column supposed to be?

Comment: The count where col5 from file b greater than 0 per line matched with file a.

Comment: That's really confusing wording. Looking more at the wanted output, it's the number of times each line starting with the same col1,col2 prefix appears in the output?

Comment: Exactly, I only want to count the match between two files when col5 is greater than 0 but my keys are col1 and col2.

Comment: Let me explain in another way. I want know how many times the line of file A match with file B but only with col5 from B is > 0. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use autodie;
use English;

# Read file1, saving the first two fields.
my %filea;
open my $filea, "<", $ARGV[0];
while (<$filea>) {
  my @F = split /,/;
  $filea{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} = 1;
}

# Read fileb
my %fileb;
open my $fileb, "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$fileb>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /,/;
  next unless $F[4] > 0; # Skip rows where the fifth column is 0 or less
  push @{$fileb{$F[0]}->{$F[1]}}, \@F; # Save the others
}

$OFS = ",";
# For each unique col1,col2 in filea, print the matching lines from fileb
# with added count.
for my $col1 (sort keys %filea) {
  next unless exists $fileb{$col1};
  for my $col2 (sort keys %{$filea{$col1}}) {
    next unless exists $fileb{$col1}->{$col2};
    my $rows = $fileb{$col1}->{$col2};
    my $count = @$rows;
    say @$_, $count for @$rows;
  }
}
```

To get the right counts, you have to read every line with the prefix you're counting before printing out those lines. If the input files are known to be sorted a smarter implementation can be written to take advantage of that and not have to read the entire files before outputting anything.

Comment: What about " $filea{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} += 1; ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't give the output. It gives a syntax error. But when you fix that and add the missing newline, you get this:

```
201843,12345,3,4,2,5,1
201843,12345,4,4,5,5,2
201844,33333,3,0,9,10,3
201844,33333,4,0,9,10,4
201844,33333,5,0,10,10,5
```

Notice that the counter value increments on each line - it's not stuck at 5 as in your output.

And that's a big clue to what's going wrong here. Or, rather, the **two** things that are going wrong here. Firstly, you can't have just one counter - you need to keep a separate counter for each of your col1/col2 combinations. And secondly, you can't start to print any output until you've processed both files - as it's impossible to know what values those counters will reach until you've seen all of `FileB`.

Here's how I've rewritten your code. It's possible that it could be simplified, but I'm afraid I don't have the time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
open my $fh_a, '<', 'FileA' or die $!;

# Phase 1: Read FileA into a hash
# This is very similar to your existing code
my %file_a;

while (<$fh_a>) {
  chomp;
  my @cols = split /,/;
  $file_a{"$cols[0],$cols[1]"} = $cols[2];
}

# Phase 2: Process FileB
# Store data in two variables.
# %counts contains the current value of the various counters.
# @outout contains one array ref for each line you want to output.
# The sub-arrays all contain two elements.
# The first element is the input line from FileB.
# The second element is the key you need to get the correct count
# for this line.
open my $fh_b, '<', 'FileB' or die $!;

my %counts;
my @output;

while (<$fh_b>) {
  chomp;
  my @cols = split /,/;

  next unless exists $file_a{"$cols[0],$cols[1]"};
  next unless $cols[4] > 0;

  ++$counts{"$cols[0],$cols[1]"};
  push @output, [$_, "$cols[0],$cols[1]"];
}

# Phase 3: Produce output.
# Walk the @output array and display a) the original line
# from FileB and b) the final counter value for lines of that type.
for (@output) {
  say join ',', $_->[0], $counts{$_->[1]};
}
```